# Problem with Hive table data in json format

Tags: json, hive, tweets

I need help with uploading tweets data in json format into Hive table and run some query.
I don't know if it is matter to my problem I'm using Hive on Google cloud platform.

my data looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke8V3.png)

CREATE external TABLE if not exists tweets_table (
id BIGINT,
text STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'

This is my schema for the table.

I can run select * from tweets_table and get a result.
but when I run any other query. I get error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1rHY.jpg)

I have tried everything I can think of. but I am new.
so please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Pls share the SQL that's failing.